# How to NOT map a foreign key id in EF (code first)?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Okay, let me first explain that THIS IS NOT MY CODE. I'm taking over a project from another employee. Anyway, this project is using Code First. I'm fixing a performance issue but I'm getting a weird error.

I've basically got two mapped classes to deal with. I'll make up short versions to be concise.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; } //primary key
    //attributes here, not important

    public int UserProfileId { get; set; } //foreign key id *i added this*
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; } //foreign key *i added this*
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //primary key
    //attributes here, not important
}
```

Now, this is a pretty standard foreign key relationship. However, there is a caveat. These tables are being pulled down from older tables, like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("application_user");
```

Then, each of the columns is mapped to a column of the pulled table using the name.
However, I'm trying to merge these two tables into a one-to-one relationship, like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(x => x.UserProfile)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserProfileId); //ERROR HERE - THIS COLUMN DOES NOT EXIST IN THE ORIGINAL TABLE
```

Now, the error, as far as I can tell, is that in the PREVIOUS table, there was no foreign key column of (UserProfileId), so I'm getting an Invalid Column Name error.

Is there a way I can just not map the foreign key id column and still maintain the one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Does your `application_user` a FK to `UserProfile` table? Or the PK of `UserProfile` is also an FK to `application_user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said there isn't a UserProfileId on the User table, you're defining a 1:1 relationship, where the User and UserProfile table share a primary key correct?

If so you can map it like this:

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasRequired(u => u.UserProfile)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

and that will generate a database like this:

[image]